# How to submit a form in a page which is being accessed by AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, form-submit

I am trying to figure out how to submit a form in a page being accessed by AJAX?

Here are some code snippets to help demonstrate what I am trying to say.

HTML BODY - THIS IS WHAT THE USER WILL SEE:

```
  <html>
    <head>
     <script language="javascript" src="linktoajaxfile.js">
    </head>
    <body onLoad="gotoPage(0)">
    <div id="fillThis">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ajax file:

```
var xmlhttp

function gotoPage(phase)
{
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
  return;
  }
var url="pageofstuffce.php";
url=url+"?stg="+phase;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("fillThis").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
// code for IE6, IE5
return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
return null;
}
```

PAGE OF DATA:

```
<?php
  $stage = $_GET['stg'];

  if($stage == 0)
  {
     echo '<a onClick="gotoPage(1)">click me</a>';
  }
  elseif($stage == 1)
  {
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
  }
  elseif(somehow can reach here)
  {
     show data from form.
  }
?>
```

How to get past the form and display the data in the same page?

I have tried submitting the form to itself (same file) and that destroyed the AJAX link, and opened the page. I have also tried just having the button move the page onto another step, but the `$_POST` variable is empty.

Comment: can you isolate the problem a little more?  Does the `pageofstuffce.php` open?  does it echo/return what you expect?  Add some alerts in there, go to`pageofstuffce.php` manually.  pinpoint a little bit so we can help better

Comment: yeah, sorry, first time posting here, am getting the hang of things still.. anyways, yes, it does what i expect it to, right up until submitting the form. Normally what i would do for submitting a form is to link the forms action back to the same file, and have a `if($_POST['submit'])` clause at the beginning of the file and it would all go on from there.. that doesn't work now, because in doing that, it then loads the `pageofstuffce.php` into the browser, instead of calling it with ajax.

Comment: Is there a way that the form can be submitted, and then the data can then be accessed from the page whithout loading the file in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hey u can go through this link**

http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/how_to_submit_a_form_with_ajax_in_jquery.php

let me know if any issues regarding this

Comment: Thanks. this works, but only when your viewing the actual file loaded into the browser; if the file is called through Ajax, then tries to do this, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can u explain more deeply whats the isssue?

Comment: i am calling a file in via ajax, and in the file being called, there is a form. i want to be able to submit data in that form, and access the data, without having to go to another page.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug in your code. You are not setting the stage variable anywhere.

Look at:

```
url=url+"?stg="+phase;
```

Probably you'll have to change stg => stage.
Don't see any other issue with it.

Comment: yeah, sorry, am using old code and trying to fix it up for the snippets.. check it again, it works..

Comment: can you be a little clear on where you are stuck. From what I understand, you see the form, i.e., stage =1. And then you submit the form and what happens next? From code it seems that the whole page reloads? Is that what is the problem?

Comment: pretty much it. I just would like to know how i can submit the form and display the data within the page calling the Ajax.

Comment: let me rephrase- I would like to know how i could perhaps submit the form in the page being called by the Ajax, and show it in the same form without losing the Ajax connection? does that make sense?

Comment: ok, try this with your form then <form onsubmit="gotoPage(2); return false;"> . This will essentially call your method gotoPage() without reloading your page when you click submit. You can even access the input field from there like document.getElementByName("name").value

Comment: shall try that now! thanks! also, with this process, can i access the input fields with php? you know, like `$_POST['name']` etc..?

Comment: Ok, have tried this, and i get to the next stage, but once i have done that, i can't seem to access any data? It can't be as hard as it seems to me right now...

Comment: Well to access the form data in php, you'll have to send the AJAX request again to your php page with the form values. So something like url=url+"?name="+document.getElementByName("name").value;. Then access it in php using $_GET['name']

Comment: oh, ok then, thanks :) am looking at other methods, but if i can't find any, i can fall back on this. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Hi for displaying the result or form in the same page u can use

form method ="POST" action =

or if u want to use ajax then write one function in jquery something like this 
function call() {

$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'path to same file name?action=submit',
 // data u want to pass 
  data:',
  success:function() {

}
});

}//function ends

and ur php code
check if $_GET['action'] is there then execute ur function

Thanks

Comment: Hey Sanil, Thanks for this, but i have never even seen jQuery, let alone tried to script it.. do you think you could either perhaps give me a link to which i can learn from, or make a script that i could understand a little better please? Thanks

Comment: do u want to display the result in the same page using ajax?

Comment: yes, but can that be done in a page being called from ajax itself?

Comment: yes on ur submit button call one js function that will call other file via ajax as explained earlier .....

Answer (score 0):

Here are the scripts that you are looking for.

**pageofstuffce.php**

```
<?php
  $stage = $_GET['stg'];

  if($stage == 0)
  {
     echo '<a onClick="gotoPage(1)">click me</a>';
  }
  elseif($stage == 1)
  {
    echo '<form>
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>';
  }
  else
  {
     echo 'show data from form.';
  }
?>
```

**Your HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="linktoajaxfile.js"></script>
        </head>

    <body onload="gotoPage(0)">
        <div id="fillThis">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript for making Ajax Calls linktoajaxfile.js**

```
var xmlhttp

function gotoPage(phase)
{


xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
  return;
  }
var url="pageofstuffce.php";
url=url+"?stg="+phase;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("fillThis").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
// code for IE6, IE5
return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
return null;
}
```

Hope this will Help!

Thanks!

Hussain.